# Using Letrec to swap variables

Tags: scheme, racket

I expect the following code to swap the variables but I get undefined error

```
(let ([me "Tarzan"]
      [you "Jane"])
    (letrec ([you me]
             [me you]
             )
      (list me you)))
```

Comment: you should have included the error message in full.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `let` here:

```
(let ([me "Tarzan"]  ; <-------.
      [you "Jane"])  ; <-------|---.
  (let ([you me]     ; me: ----^   |
        [me you])    ; you: -------^
    (list me you)))
;; '("Jane" "Tarzan")
```

In fact, you *should* use `let` here, since `letrec` bindings refer to each other, causing the vicious circle when a variable must know the other one's value to be initialized, but that other variable's value refers back to the first one, ad infinitum.

But `let` bindings' initialization expressions simply refer to the *outer* *scope*.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this doesn't swap anything, it just uses the same names in a new scope.

It is exactly the same as

```
(let ([me "Tarzan"] 
      [you "Jane"]) 
     (letrec ([a b] 
              [b a]) 
         (list b a)))
```

which makes the problem visible; the bindings in `letrec` refer to each other in a recursion that never ends.

If you use `let`,

```
(let ([me "Tarzan"]
      [you "Jane"])
    (let ([you me]
          [me you])
      (list me you)))
```

it will work, but it still doesn't really *swap* anything for the same reason as above – this is equivalent to

```
(let ([me "Tarzan"]
      [you "Jane"])
    (let ([a me]
          [b you])
      (list b a)))
```